# Survival data simulation based on confidence interval of Hazard ratio

Tags: survival, simulation, hazard

I got a published hazard ratio (HR) of 0.464 with 95%CI as (0.337, 0.639) from a paper.

My question is

1. How can I get the distribution of the HR, so that I can check the different quantiles?
2. is that possible to reconstruct patient level data via simulation if we know the median survival time of each group is 6.9 vs 4.3 (4.3/6.9 is not exactly 0.464) but the model adjusted HR is still consistent with 0.464 with 95%CI as (0.337, 0.639)?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. If HR distribution is unknown, then its reconstruction is impossible solely based on maximum likelihood and confidence interval. If model is known and simple enough (e.g. binomial distribution) AND number of samples is known, one can reconstruct the model (e.g. in case of binomial, MLE is directly an estimate of the model parameter).
2. You cannot reconstruct patient level data out of anything other than patient level data :D. You can run a simulation to generate data similar to that of the true patient data based on the model parameters. If you know the true model, you can answer your own question: if the parameters you provide are enough to run a simulation unambiguously, then yes it is possible, otherwise no. If you don't know the model, we don't know it either :D